# Wordpress Rest API - Retrieving header authorization credentials and passing my own success or failure

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to do away with how WordPress deals with credentials when using the Rest API and program my own.  is there some kind of action or filter for this?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate_user/

Comment: This does not do what I need.  I need to remove WordPress Rest API authentication.